# Angular application does not load after proxy configuration

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, cors

I am trying to setup angular 7 application's proxy config as I am facing issue with so called CORS error while calling a Java JAX-RS REST service from angular application.

```
  {
    context: [
      "**",
    ],
    target: "http://server_on_which_rest_api_is_running:9090",
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
  },
];

module.exports = PROXY_DEV_CONFIG;
```

The reason I had to give ** is I have lots of endpoints having query/path params like this.

`labels/bylocal?menuId=0`
But when is use this query/path param angular gives 500 error code.

So now I am stuck with following screen and have no idea why is this happening.

[image]

[image]

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500 returned by server when u call api ?

Comment: When i use multiple proxy endpoints like ```labels/bylocal?menuId=0 ```

Comment: Does angular proxy configuration supports query parameter or path variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we used when running the local Angular app and local REST API server.

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8083",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

In general, what is done: All calls to REST server are prefixed with "api/", and then proxy knows to redirect it directly to the server.